# Reload a const from external page ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I imported my menu to the another page:
`import Sidebar from "../Sidebar.js";`

However, I need to select a store on the main page, and currently I need to refresh the entire page for that store's options to appear in the menu. If I only updated the menu, there would be no need to update the entire page and the site would look more elegant!

In the const, I tried:

```
const shopSelect = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/select', {
                sel: sel
            });
            Sidebar(); (Here before was a window.location.reload)
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response);
            }
        }
    }
```

With this current code, the menu does not update! How can I update the menu without having to refresh the whole page? Thanks!

Comment: Can you psost the code for SideBar? What is happening in that function because with your current question I am not sure what you are exactly trying to achieve!

Comment: The `axios.post` request only notifies the server of the change. You'll have to inform React as well. This is probably done by updating a state or context.

Comment: @AhsanIhsan I tried to put the "export default function Sidebar()" And I also tried to put a const created inside Sidebar.js, Even importing them, I can't update inside my other file

Comment: @3limin4t0r The question is about this, I want to update a state, but from an external file "Sidebar.js"

Comment: Well if you want to stick with your current solution, you should pass the method that updates your value inside the component props and call it in the component @HarrisonMartes

Comment: Is `Sidebar` a React component? How does it currently get its contents? Assuming `<Sidebar />` is a React component, you should probably lift up the state of `Sidebar`, such that your current component can manage it. If this description matches your scenario, check out the guide [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the React documentation.